# How do I define a custom @context for a verifiable credential?

Tags: json-ld, linked-data

Here is an example of a verifiable credential I want to create

```json
{
  "@context": ["https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1"],
  "credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:not-a-real-did",
    "competence": ["AM", "B"],
    "dateOfBirth": "1995-09-23",
    "name": "Frank Franksson",
    "picture": "some-random-url.png",
    "ssn": "19950923-9965"
  },
  "holder": "did:ethr:goerli:0x027d0d3347a44b5469a8acd6e9195f6e5c3b7253ddce558238d096dd927b23055a",
  "id": "https://verify.stepstone.com/credentials/c7c077a6-f0c0-4843-9718-68dfba008587",
  "issuanceDate": "2022-11-18T09:00:38.000Z",
  "issuer": {
    "id": "did:ethr:goerli:0x02f163e34f0c84d85bf0b5becc119c86362e36fab4c9247515610a0b1cc4eff74a"
  },
  "proof": {
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NksiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.-9Kd8qEpZXNDWw-RsHO9nzh-citxi8yaas_Yhaxfx4ykj4HqJz3h3SvD94HRRTWFRvXty8z2Hl3FP1vCExVLIg",
    "type": "JwtProof2020"
  },
  "type": [
    "VerifiablePresentation",
    "VerifiableCredential",
    "SwedishDriversLicense"
  ]
}
```

But right now I'm only using the standard `@context` for verifiable credentials, I also want to include the custom fields for my specific verifiable credential like so:

```json
{
  "@context": 
       [
        "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
        "https://www.example.org/2022/swedish-drivers-license.jsonld"
       ],
   ....
}
```

How do I define my custom context `https://www.example.org/2022/swedish-drivers-license.jsonld` so that it matches my credential? Do I have to build on top of someone else's ontology or can is it possible for me to define the base definitions myself? How do I define that there is a required field "name" of type "string"?

This is how far I've gotten:

```json
{
  "@context": [
    {
    "competence": "http://example.com/vocabulary#competence",
    "dateOfBirth": "http://example.com/vocabulary#dateOfBirth",
    "name": "http://example.com/vocabulary#name",
    "picture": "http://example.com/vocabulary#picture",
    "ssn": "http://example.com/vocabulary#ssn",
    }
  ]
}
```

But everything is just a uri and all examples I've found also just keep defining things in terms of more uri:s until they end at `"http://schema.org/"`. Can I define what an `"ssn"` myself is without referencing a third party?

**Update 1**

Here is my current solution:

```json
{
  "@context": [
    "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
    {
      "competence": "https://schema.org/swedishdriverslicence/competence",
      "dateOfBirth": "https://schema.org/birthDate",
      "name": "https://schema.org/givenName",
      "picture": {
        "@id": "http://schema.org/image",
        "@type": "@id"
      },
      "ssn": "https://example.org/sweden/ssn"
    }
  ],
  "credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:not-a-real-did",
    "competence": ["AM", "B"],
    "dateOfBirth": "1995-09-23",
    "name": "Frank Franksson",
    "picture": "some-random-url.png",
    "ssn": "19950923-9965"
  },
  "holder": "did:ethr:goerli:0x027d0d3347a44b5469a8acd6e9195f6e5c3b7253ddce558238d096dd927b23055a",
  "id": "https://example.org/credentials/c7c077a6-f0c0-4843-9718-68dfba008587",
  "issuanceDate": "2022-11-18T09:00:38.000Z",
  "issuer": {
    "id": "did:ethr:goerli:0x02f163e34f0c84d85bf0b5becc119c86362e36fab4c9247515610a0b1cc4eff74a"
  },
  "proof": {
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NksiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.-9Kd8qEpZXNDWw-RsHO9nzh-citxi8yaas_Yhaxfx4ykj4HqJz3h3SvD94HRRTWFRvXty8z2Hl3FP1vCExVLIg",
    "type": "JwtProof2020"
  },
  "type": [
    "VerifiablePresentation",
    "VerifiableCredential",
    "SwedishDriversLicense"
  ]
}
```

You can view it in the [playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-table&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%5B%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2018%2Fcredentials%2Fv1%22%2C%7B%22competence%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fswedishdriverslicence%2Fcompetence%22%2C%22dateOfBirth%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FbirthDate%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FgivenName%22%2C%22picture%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fimage%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22ssn%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fsweden%2Fssn%22%7D%5D%2C%22credentialSubject%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22did%3Aexample%3Anot-a-real-did%22%2C%22competence%22%3A%5B%22AM%22%2C%22B%22%5D%2C%22dateOfBirth%22%3A%221995-09-23%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Frank%20Franksson%22%2C%22picture%22%3A%22some-random-url.png%22%2C%22ssn%22%3A%2219950923-9965%22%7D%2C%22holder%22%3A%22did%3Aethr%3Agoerli%3A0x027d0d3347a44b5469a8acd6e9195f6e5c3b7253ddce558238d096dd927b23055a%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fcredentials%2Fc7c077a6-f0c0-4843-9718-68dfba008587%22%2C%22issuanceDate%22%3A%222022-11-18T09%3A00%3A38.000Z%22%2C%22issuer%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22did%3Aethr%3Agoerli%3A0x02f163e34f0c84d85bf0b5becc119c86362e36fab4c9247515610a0b1cc4eff74a%22%7D%2C%22proof%22%3A%7B%22jwt%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NksiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.-9Kd8qEpZXNDWw-RsHO9nzh-citxi8yaas_Yhaxfx4ykj4HqJz3h3SvD94HRRTWFRvXty8z2Hl3FP1vCExVLIg%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22JwtProof2020%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22VerifiablePresentation%22%2C%22VerifiableCredential%22%2C%22SwedishDriversLicense%22%5D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Verifiable Credentials data model and specifically the [extensibility section](https://www.w3.org/TR/vc-data-model/#extensibility)

You can definitely define it the way you are. the other way around it is to host your context file somewhere like: https://example.com/contexts/mycontext.jsonld

Using this you can create a Credential like this (and then sign it with various different libraries to create a **Verifiable Credential**):

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
    "https://example.com/contexts/mycontext.jsonld"
  ],
  "id": "http://example.com/credentials/4643",
  "type": ["VerifiableCredential", "CustomExt12"],
  "issuer": "https://example.com/issuers/14",
  "issuanceDate": "2018-02-24T05:28:04Z",
  "referenceNumber": 83294847,
  "credentialSubject": {
    "id": "did:example:abcdef1234567",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "favoriteFood": "Papaya"
  }
}
```

for the sake of the argument and just to give you a real world example, you can see this [context](https://sphereon-opensource.github.io/vc-contexts/fma/gaia-x.jsonld) which is defining a gaia-x context. And in this real world example, you can create the following VerifiableCredential:

```
{
    "@context": [
      "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
      "https://sphereon-opensource.github.io/vc-contexts/fma/gaia-x.jsonld"
    ],
    "type": [
      "VerifiableCredential",
      "ParticipantCredential"
    ],
    "id": "https://catalogue.gaia-x.eu/credentials/ParticipantCredential/1678184115309",
    "issuer": "did:web:issuer",
    "issuanceDate": "CURRENT_DATE",
    "credentialSubject": {
      "id": "did:web:subject",
      "hash": "0555950f9db2264aef89b1800d88ad8d5952d69b6d93517981d4d060b807902c"
    },
    "proof": {
      "type": "JsonWebSignature2020",
      "created": "DATE",
      "proofPurpose": "assertionMethod",
      "jws": "JWS_SIGNATURE",
      "verificationMethod": "did:web:issuer#JWK2020-RSA"
    }
  }
```